# Virial of a system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, virial-theorem

I had obtained

$$\overline{E_{kin}} = -\frac{1}{2}\overline{\sum_j\mathbf{r}_j\cdot\mathbf{F}_j}$$

and was asked to show that if the forces are conservative then

$$\overline{E_{kin}} = \frac{1}{2}\overline{\sum_j\mathbf{r}_j\cdot\mathbf{\nabla}_jE_{pot}}$$

where $E_{pot} = \sum_{1\leq j,k\leq n}^{j<k} V_{jk}(\mathbf{r}_j-\mathbf{r}_k)$ is the total potential energy.

I had tried to proceed by noticing that $\mathbf{F}_j = \sum_{k(\neq j)}\mathbf{F}_{jk}$

$$\overline{E_{kin}} = -\frac{1}{2}\overline{\sum_j\mathbf{r}_j\cdot\mathbf{F}_j}\quad\quad\\
\quad \quad= -\frac{1}{2}\overline{\sum_j \mathbf{r}_j\cdot \sum_{k(\neq j)}\mathbf{F}_{jk}}$$

Substituting $\mathbf{F}_{jk} = -\nabla _j V_{jk}(\mathbf{r}_j-\mathbf{r}_k)$,

$$-\frac{1}{2}\overline{\sum_j \mathbf{r}_j\cdot \sum_{k(\neq j)}\mathbf{F}_{jk}}\qquad\qquad\\
\quad=\frac{1}{2}\overline{\sum_j \mathbf{r}_j\cdot \sum_{k(\neq j)}\nabla _j V_{jk}(\mathbf{r}_j-\mathbf{r}_k)} $$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\overline{\sum_j \mathbf{r}_j\cdot \nabla _j\sum_{k(\neq j)} V_{jk}(\mathbf{r}_j-\mathbf{r}_k)}$$

How do you show that $\sum_{k(\neq j)} V_{jk}(\mathbf{r}_j-\mathbf{r}_k) = \sum_{1\leq j,k\leq n}^{j<k} V_{jk}(\mathbf{r}_j-\mathbf{r}_k)$?

Comment: Could you clarify the summation in the definition of $E_{pot}$? Is it over all pairs of j and k where j<k? $E_{pot}$ is an index-less object, so you should be careful in your last step.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. Impose the following symmetry condition on the potential energy: 
   $$\tag{1}V_{i\ell}({\bf r}_i-{\bf r}_{\ell})~=~(i \leftrightarrow \ell).$$
2. Calculate from the definition
   $$\tag{2} E_{\rm pot} ~:=~ \sum_{1\leq i,\ell\leq n}^{i<\ell} V_{i\ell}(\mathbf{r}_i-\mathbf{r}_{\ell})$$
   that
   $$ \nabla_j E_{\rm pot}~\stackrel{(1)+(2)}{=}~
   \nabla_j\sum_{1\leq \ell\leq n}^{\ell>j}V_{j\ell}(\mathbf{r}_j-\mathbf{r}_{\ell})
   +\nabla_j\sum_{1\leq i\leq n}^{i<j}V_{ji}(\mathbf{r}_j-\mathbf{r}_i) $$
   $$\tag{3}~=~\nabla_j\sum_{1\leq i\leq n}^{i\neq j}V_{ji}(\mathbf{r}_j-\mathbf{r}_{i}) $$